# vertical lines in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make vertical lines between words, with indents in them... I've found a few things online, but still a bit confused.

What I have so far:

[image: What I have]

How I want them to look:

[image: How I want them to look]

I know how to create links, and a vertical line, but I'm having trouble finding how to indent between words and put a vertical line between there.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: can you procide some codes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what to [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mre] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets)

Comment: Please provide us some codes relevant to the topic so we can understand better what's going on, the one you posted are result and the expected output in an image format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS and `border`.
Remove the right border from the `:last-child`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.links a {
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
  border-right: 2px solid #888;
}

.links a:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row links">
  <a href="#">Some link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Some link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Some link 4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `border-left` property and use it on every prepend child

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

a + a {
  border-left: 2px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like your `a + a` solution. Good job

Answer (score -4):

wrap all your elements inside a `div` with `display:flex`

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
   
   **your codes**

</div>

.wrapper{
    display: flex;
}
```